# How can I show a context menu only when the user has clicked the root node in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, contextmenu

I have a TreeView and a Context Menu. I want to show the Context Menu ONLY when I right click on the ROOT node and not the child nodes.

This is what I have so far. This shows the Context Menu even when I right click on the child nodes. How can I change this so that the Menu shows only when I right click on the root node? Is it possible?

```
if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
    // Select the clicked node
    treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

    if(treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        myContextMenuStrip.Show(treeView1, e.Location)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you'll need to add some logic to your `if` statements that verifies the node the user clicked on is a root node.

But how do we find out if it's a root node? Well, thinking it through, we can define a root node as one that does not have any parents. So you can simply check the [`Parent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.parent.aspx) of the `TreeNode` and make sure that it is `null`.

Modify your code to look something like this:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
    // Select the clicked node
    treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

    if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null && treeView.SelectedNode.Parent == null)
    {
        myContextMenuStrip.Show(treeView1, e.Location)
    }
}
```

You want to retain the check that the node itself is not `null`, because you don't want to show the context menu when they *haven't* clicked on a node, but you need to *add* the check for a parent, because that tells you whether or not it's a root node. The way you indicate that programmatically is using a logical AND, which is the `&&` operator in C#.

Comment: That did the jobb. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the node you clicked on is the root node instead of checking for it being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Level` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/386b25wy(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
  ' Select the clicked node
  treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y)

  If treeView1.SelectedNode.Level = 0 Then
    myContextMenuStrip.Show(treeView1, e.Location)
  End If
End If
```